# Flutter: Admin login

Tags: flutter, dart

I successfully did the register and login page.
Now I want to have when a specific user which has the role of admin logs in that it will navigate him to admin home page, if it has a user role it will navigate them to homepage.
How can I do this? can someone help me with this?
I only have one admin. So, every user has the role user except one
this is what the role looks like [admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgPxK.png).

This is my login code:

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

 final Function toggleView;
  LoginPage({this.toggleView ,Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController emailInputController;
  TextEditingController pwdInputController;

  @override
  initState() {
    emailInputController = new TextEditingController();
    pwdInputController = new TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  String emailValidator(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Email format is invalid';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  String pwdValidator(String value) {
    if (value.length < 8) {
      return 'Password must be longer than 8 characters';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Login"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Form(
              key: _loginFormKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email*', hintText: "john.doe@gmail.com"),
                    controller: emailInputController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    validator: emailValidator,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Password*', hintText: "********"),
                    controller: pwdInputController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: pwdValidator,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Login"),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        FirebaseAuth.instance
                            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                                email: emailInputController.text,
                                password: pwdInputController.text)
                            .then((currentUser) => Firestore.instance
                                .collection("users")
                                .document()
                                .get()
                                .then((DocumentSnapshot result) =>
                                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => Home() ))
                                .catchError((err) => print(err)))
                            .catchError((err) => print(err)));
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  Text("Don't have an account yet?"),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Register!"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder:(context){
                                            return RegisterPage();
                                          }));
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ))));
  }
}
```

Sign out sign in functions:

```
class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

// auth change user stream 
Stream<User>get user {
  return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
    .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}


// sign in emailpass
Future signInwithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password ) async {
  try {
    AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password:password );
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;

    return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

  } catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;

  }
}

// register with emailpass
Future registerwithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password,String displayName
) async {
  try {
    AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password:password );
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      if(user != null){
      UserUpdateInfo updateUser = UserUpdateInfo();
      updateUser.displayName = displayName;
      user.updateProfile(updateUser);}
    return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

    

    
    

  } catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;

  }
  
}

// sign out 
Future signOut() async {
  try{
    return await _auth.signOut();
  } 
  
  catch(e) {
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }


}
}
```

Sign up:

```
class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  
  final Function toggleView;
  RegisterPage({this.toggleView ,Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterPageState createState() => _RegisterPageState();
}

class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _registerFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController fullNameInputController;
  TextEditingController emailInputController;
  TextEditingController pwdInputController;
  TextEditingController confirmPwdInputController;

  @override
  initState() {
    fullNameInputController = new TextEditingController();
    emailInputController = new TextEditingController();
    pwdInputController = new TextEditingController();
    confirmPwdInputController = new TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  String emailValidator(String value) {
    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Email format is invalid';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  String pwdValidator(String value) {
    if (value.length < 8) {
      return 'Password must be longer than 8 characters';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Register"),
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Form(
              key: _registerFormKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Full Name*', hintText: "John"),
                    controller: fullNameInputController,
                    validator: (displayName) {
                      if (displayName.length < 3) {
                        return "Please enter a valid first name.";
                      }
                      
                    },
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Email*', hintText: "john.doe@gmail.com"),
                    controller: emailInputController,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    validator: emailValidator,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Password*', hintText: "********"),
                    controller: pwdInputController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: pwdValidator,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Confirm Password*', hintText: "********"),
                    controller: confirmPwdInputController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    validator: pwdValidator,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("Register"),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (_registerFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        if (pwdInputController.text ==
                            confirmPwdInputController.text) {
                          try {
            final FirebaseUser user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: emailInputController.text,
                    password: pwdInputController.text
                )).user;
            
            await Firestore.instance
                .collection("users")
                .document(user.uid)
                .setData({
                    "uid": user.uid,
                    "Fname": fullNameInputController.text,
                    "email": emailInputController.text,
                    "role": "user",
                    "createdAt": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 
                });
                                  
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder:(context){
                                            return Home();
                                            
                                          }));
        } catch (e) {
            print('Error Happened!!!: $e');
        }  
                            }}}),
                  Text("Already have an account?"),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Login here!"),
                    onPressed: () {
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder:(context){
                                            return LoginPage();
                                          }));                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a document name to be able to query user information when logging in. Just pass the user email or uid.

[image]

Then wrap your Homepage with a FutureBuilder, to get current user data, and a StreamBuilder to query database document. It should look something like this!

```
Future<FirebaseUser> currentUser() async {
  FirebaseAuth _firebaseInstance = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  return _firebaseInstance.currentUser();
}

return FutureBuilder(
  future: currentUser(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .document(snapshot.data.email) // or uid
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data["role"] == "admin") {
              // return admin page
            } else {
              // return home page
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      );
    }
    return Container();
  },
);
```

Comment: i did this it worked but it will always return me to the adminhomepage

Comment: Hi! Make sure to change the user role. If the users role is equal to admin, the builder will return adminhomepage. There is no way snapshot.data["role"] == "admin" is true, while the users role is different from admin

Comment: in my firebase all the users has user role except for one has an admin role but it still returns me to adminhomepage

Comment: Share your sign in, up and out functions. Maybe you are doing it the wrong way and firebase is not registering a new user.

Comment: I've edited my post of what you asked. whenever I register a new user it shows up in the firebase